# How to send my json array to sevaral rows in my sql database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, json

I got several elements called workers, they all got an id, position left, and position top. 
I have made it to an array and then made it to a json object, which a would like to send to my database. but when i test it, in the controller and model, it says the value is null. 
what to do?

the first function:

```
function GetUnitInfo(){

          for(i=0 ; i < $('.Worker').length ; i++){
          $('.Worker').each(function(){

                aUnitsInfo = [{'unitid':$(this).attr("id"),
                              'unitposleft':$(this).position().left,
                              'unitpostop':$(this).position().top
                            }];

                 jUnitsInfo.push(aUnitsInfo[i]);
                 aUnitsInfo = JSON.stringify(jUnitsInfo);    

               console.log(i);

          });
          console.log("unitinfo: "+jUnitsInfo[i].unitid);
         console.log("uniposleft: "+jUnitsInfo[i].unitposleft);
         console.log("unitpostop: "+jUnitsInfo[i].unitpostop);
         console.dir(jUnitsInfo[i]);
        }

          }
```

in my log i see 3 objects with the correct values.

then i want to send it to the database:

```
setInterval(function(){    
                SaveUnits();
                function SaveUnits()
                {   

                   GetUnitInfo();


                    $sLoginEmail = $('#TxtLoginEmail').val();
                    // TODO: Check that the email is valid
                    // console.log("The email is:"+$sLoginEmail); 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'bridge.php',
                        data: {"sFunction":"SaveUnits", "unitsInfo":jUnitsInfo[i]},
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            $oXml = $(data);

                        }
                    });
                }
        },5000);
```

And here's where it get's tricky. I know from the first function that my jUnitsInfo[i] is containing the right objects but after this part it seems to be null.

this is my bridge:

```
     if($_POST['sFunction'] == "SaveUnits")
{
    require_once 'Controllers/UserController.php';
    $oUnitsInfo = new USerController();
    echo $oUnitsInfo->SaveUnits($_POST['unitsInfo']); 
}
```

The Controller:

```
    public function SaveUnits($unitsInfo)
{require_once 'Models/UserModel.php';
    $oUserModel = new UserModel();
    $unitsInfo = json_decode($unitsInfo);
    $saveUnits = $oUserModel->SaveUnits($unitsInfo);}
```

and the model:

```
    public function SaveUnits($unitsInfo){        
    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","awesomegame");
    // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $unitsInfo = array(); 
    foreach( $unitsInfo as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['unitId']).'", '.$row['unitPosTop'].','.$row['unitPosLeft'].')';
    }
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO units (unitid, unitpostop, unitposleft) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));}}
```

And when i var dump it in the controller
var_dump(json_decode($unitsInfo));
it just comes back with a null.

how do i send the array correctly? - and get the values written to the database on drifferent rows (one for each worker).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like

```
 jUnitsInfo[i]
```

is reasonable since you are out of the for loop.

Take the code

```
function GetUnitInfoAndSave(){
        var jUnitsInfo=[];
      $('.Worker').each(function(){

            var aUnitsInfo ={'unitid':$(this).attr("id"),
                          'unitposleft':$(this).position().left,
                          'unitpostop':$(this).position().top
                        };

             jUnitsInfo.push(aUnitsInfo); 
      });

      for(var i=0 ; i < jUnitsInfo.length ; i++){

       var $sLoginEmail = $('#TxtLoginEmail').val();
                // TODO: Check that the email is valid
                // console.log("The email is:"+$sLoginEmail); 
        var data=$.extend({},{sFunction:"SaveUnits"},jUnitsInfo[i]);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'bridge.php',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $oXml = $(data);

                    }
                });

      //console.log("unitinfo: "+jUnitsInfo[i].unitid);
     //console.log("uniposleft: "+jUnitsInfo[i].unitposleft);
     //console.log("unitpostop: "+jUnitsInfo[i].unitpostop);
     //console.dir(jUnitsInfo[i]);
    }
}
setInterval(GetUnitInfoAndSave,5000);
```

PS: $.Ajax and setInterval functions are asynchronous, so you don't know when data are really sent to the server. (This code sends the array items one after another)